# Flow.js Extend imported type

Tags: javascript, inheritance, flowtype

I'm trying to extend a Flow Type that I am importing from an external library like so:

```
import type { $Request, $Response } from 'express';


export type Req extends $Request {
  additionalField: {
    key: string
  }
};
```

This won't work, but I'm wondering if there is another way to accomplish this in Flow. I need a new type that inherits a previous type and has a few more properties on top of that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might consider the [Intersection type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/), which is created using the `&` operator.

The following should work:

```
type Req = $Request & {
  additionalField: {
    key: string
  }
}
```